# How to use for loop in ajax success function?

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

This is my alert output result:

[image]

The above picture array is my result that is get from table using ajax request.but i don't know how to use in for loop and i have tired in for loop the value is splitted one by one like

[image]

My code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#TDate').on('input change', function() {
var name =$('#TDate').val();
var credit = 0;
var debit = 0;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>BookKeeping/item",
        data: {name:name},
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data); 
var result = data;
    var arr = result;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  document.write("<br><br>array index: " + i);
  var obj = arr[i];
  for (var key in obj){
    var value = obj[key];
    document.write("<br> - " + key + ": " + value);
  }
}


}

});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why have you swapped the variables in data to result and then result to arr, Ideally just check if the result you get in response is array use $.each(data, function(i, val) { // type some code here }), Further you can parse html object and append it to dom or just use your same way document write it will work best of luck.

Comment: thanks for your time i have tried another code and i got result

Comment: Oh okay you can up vote any of the below or my comments if it was helpful and share your results.

Comment: no i have tried another code not from the below the code it is my own code.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your script like this and then do whatever Logic you want for the response

```
$('#TDate').on('input change', function() {
    var name =$('#TDate').val();
    var credit = 0;
    var debit = 0;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>BookKeeping/item",
        data: {name:name},
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            myGoodFunctionToHandleResponse(data);
        }
    });
});

function myGoodFunctionToHandleResponse(data){
    for(let i in data){
        console.log(data[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have forgot to put JSON.parse() this function after success function and so i didn't get the correct result so far.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#TDate').on('input change', function() {
var name =$('#TDate').val();
var credit = 0;
var debit = 0;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>BookKeeping/item",
        data: {name:name},
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
    var result = JSON.parse(data)
var mycars = result; 
for (i in mycars)
{
    if( mycars[i].dc == "C"){
    var credit = mycars[i].Amt;
}
else{
    var debit = mycars[i].Amt;
}
if(credit > debit)
{
    var bal = credit -  debit;
}
else{
    var bal = debit - credit;
}
}
  $('#bal').val(bal);      
}

});
});
</script>
```